# Access child object for a database search call

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to search MongoDB using findOne (or find) unfortunately I'm trying to access a value from within the record but I can't seem to, perhaps it's because it's a child?

I'm trying to use order_number, which returns means the return will be null.... using domain works!

The order_number can be found within customer_details!

The database function im trying to use (simple for now) :

```
dbconnect.createConnection()
    refund.findOne({domain: domain, order_number: order_number}, (err, docs) => {            
        console.log('database return in addRefund   ' + docs)
   dbconnect.closeConnection();
    })
```

(returns null even if it exists)

the object:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c83d0d5ce02f50019b1b146"
    },
    "refundDetails": {
        "refund": {
            "shipping": {
                "amount": 10,
                "tax": 0,
                "maximum_refundable": 10
            },
            "refund_line_items": [
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "line_item_id": 1808377315391,
                    "location_id": null,
                    "restock_type": "no_restock",
                    "price": "15.44",
                    "subtotal": "15.44",
                    "total_tax": "0.00",
                    "discounted_price": "15.44",
                    "discounted_total_price": "15.44",
                    "total_cart_discount_amount": "0.00"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "line_item_id": 1808377348159,
                    "location_id": null,
                    "restock_type": "no_restock",
                    "price": "28.32",
                    "subtotal": "28.32",
                    "total_tax": "0.00",
                    "discounted_price": "28.32",
                    "discounted_total_price": "28.32",
                    "total_cart_discount_amount": "0.00"
                }
            ],
            "transactions": []
        },
        "customer_details": [
            {
                "order": {
                    "customer_name": "ewfefwefw grant",
                    "customer_email": "wefewfwefwef@yahoo.co.uk",
                    "order_id": 778365730879,
                    "order_number": 1023,
                    "order_date": "2019-02-16T05:58:57-05:00",
                    "total_price": "53.76",
                    "subtotal_price": "43.76",
                    "shipping_price": "10.00",
                    "total_tax": "0.00",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "id": 1808377315391,
                            "variant_id": 7051095769151,
                            "title": "Womens Summer Black Camis Dress",
                            "name": "Womens Summer Black Camis Dress - Black / S",
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "price": "15.44",
                            "product_id": 561553309759
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 1808377348159,
                            "variant_id": 7051095310399,
                            "title": "2017 Summer Women Dress Sexy",
                            "name": "2017 Summer Women Dress Sexy - Black / L",
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "price": "28.32",
                            "product_id": 561553244223
                        }
                    ],
                    "image_links": [
                        {
                            "product_id": 561553309759,
                            "image_src": ewfewfwefwefw,
                            "varrient_id": []
                        },
                        {
                            "product_id": 561553309759,
                            "image_src": ewfewfwefewf,
                            "varrient_id": [
                                7051095769151,
                                7051095834687,
                                7051095867455,
                                7051095900223
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "product_id": 561553244223,
                            "image_src": "qwfefefwe,
                            "varrient_id": []
                        }
                    ],
                    "fullfillmentText": "Hi, Please find your order details below:"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "domain": "dwdwd.wdwd.com",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you're trying to access property in a wrong way.

Try this:

```
refund.findOne({domain: domain, 'customer_details.order.order_number': order_number}, (err, docs) => {            
   console.log('database return in addRefund   ' + docs)
})
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: correct, thanks! I didn't know to make a string and access a nested object that way.